# How did Noah Bennet's glasses get broken?

Tags: heroes

Recently started re-watching *Heroes*. In the season 1 episode, ***Hiros***, Noah was talking to Brody in this hospital. Noah is wearing broken glasses.

[image]

You can clearly see the broken glasses.

Later, in another season 1 episode, ***Better Halves***, we see this:

[image]

So the show acknowldged it, but I don't remember seeing anything happen to him that would cause this. Is this ever explained?

Comment: If I remember correctly, that is after he was "killed" by Mohinder?  If so, then those are likely the glasses he was wearing when he fell to the ground after being shot.  Thus breaking them.

Comment: @Robert If I recall correctly, those glasses were (as shown in the painting) shattered completely on one side, not just cracked a bit. I _think_ the still in the question here may be from around the time when he’s trying on new glasses in the kitchen and Claire helps him choose, but I’m not sure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah.  It's been a while since I've watched Heroes, so I'm a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

Before coming to the hospital to see Claire, HRG and the Haitian were busy with dragging Nathan through a parking lot and when HRG's phone started to ring, Nathan kicked him in the face and flew away. This was when his glasses got cracked.

Comment: HRG? His Royal Giddiness?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Horn Rimmed Glasses (I think).

Comment: Hah! That's right, the writers used to refer to him in the scripts as HRG aka Horn Rimmed Glasses, and it stuck. Even now Jack Coleman uses HRG more.